# tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, django

I'll try to make a JSON

```
 for i in ktg_mhs:       
        chart_ktg ={
            'value' : ktg_mhs[i][1],
            'name' : ktg_mhs[i][0]
        }
        result.append(chart_ktg)
    
    data = json.dumps(chart_ktg)
```

but, I get an error at this

```
'value' : ktg_mhs[i][1],
'name' : ktg_mhs[i][0]
```

How to solve it and why?

I have this input :

```
(('Coding', 51), ('Database', 27), ('UI/UX', 223), ('Manajemen', 34), ('Dasar Sistem Informasi', 7), ('Bisnis', 64), ('Kesehatan', 18), ('Lain-lain', 235))
```

And I want to make JSON like this :

```
{
            value: 335,
            name: 'Coding'
            }, {
            value: 310,
            name: 'Database'
            },
```

I try this :

```
result = []
           
    chart_ktg =[
    {
        'value' : ktg_mhsi[1],
        'name' : ktg_mhsi[0]
    }
        for ktg_mhsi in ktg_mhs
    ]
        # result.append(chart_ktg)
    data = json.dumps(chart_ktg)
```

And  the output like this :

```
[{"value": 51, "name": "Coding"}, {"value": 27, "name": "Database"}, {"value": 223, "name": "UI/UX"}, {"value": 34, "name": "Manajemen"}, {"value": 7, "name": "Dasar Sistem Informasi"}, {"value": 64, "name": "Bisnis"}, {"value": 18, "name": "Kesehatan"}, {"value": 235, "name": "Lain-lain"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in ktg_mhs` will not yield the indices, but the elements of the list, so you work with:

```
for ktg_mhsi in ktg_mhs:       
    chart_ktg ={
        'value' : ktg_mhsi[1],
        'name' : ktg_mhsi[0]
    }
    result.append(chart_ktg)
data = json.dumps(chart_ktg)
```

We can replace this with list comprehension with:

```
chart_ktg = [
  {
    'value' : value,
    'name' : name
  }
  for name, value in ktg_mhs
]

data = json.dumps(chart_ktg)
```

Comment: {
            value: 335,
            name: 'Coding'
            }, ---> can I make JSON like this?

Comment: @Hazade: exactly how does the *input* and *output* looks like? [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65513877/67579) your question and provide sample input/output.

Comment: @Hazade: the output is not valid JSON: it should be wrapped in a list for example, you here have basically several small JSON blobs.

Comment: I try your solution and its work but the output is like this , [{"value": 51, "name": "Coding"}, {"value": 27, "name": "Database"}, {"value": 223, "name": "UI/UX"}, {"value": 34, "name": "Manajemen"}, {"value": 7, "name": "Dasar Sistem Informasi"}, {"value": 64, "name": "Bisnis"}, {"value": 18, "name": "Kesehatan"}, {"value": 235, "name": "Lain-lain"}]

Comment: @Hazade: yes, but what you propose is not valid JSON. Take a look at https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: Yes, cause I want parse JSON like that to Javascript, especially to edit my chart with javascript, and the value what it's need is like that

Comment: @Hazade: but it is not JSON, hence JavaScript will reject this as well. You thus should first make a *valid* JSON output format.